# How to pass an image taken from screen to another screen?

Tags: java, android, image

I made a login screen and it has the option to take the photo (it is working), but I want this photo to be sent to Activity "My Data" of the client, how to do it?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the image path as extra into the intent when you start the other activity.

```
String path = "\path\to\img";
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("PATH", path);
startActivity(i);
```

And get it on the other

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH");
```